# Using where condition to insert value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

```
insert into dbo.Repository(STATE_CODE,ZIPCODE) 
values('SA','560064'), 
WHERE JOBDIVA_ID = '23-00871';
```

output :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

SQL command for inserting data into specific row with given column name value condition.

Comment: If JOBDIVA_ID is a field in Repository table, perhaps you are looking for `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the above, exactly? What you have doesn't really make sense; you want to `INSERT` a new row, but only if the value `JOBDIVA_ID` has a specific value; where is `JOBDIVA_ID` coming from? How does it relate to the data you want to `INSERT`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming T-SQL, quite a few things wrong here...

```
insert into 
 dbo.Repository(STATE_CODE,ZIPCODE)  
values
 ('SA','560064'),  
WHERE 
 JOBDIVA_ID = '23-00871';
```

The correct INSERT command would be (assuming the datatypes are correct):

```
insert into 
 dbo.Repository(STATE_CODE,ZIPCODE)  
values
 ('SA','560064');
```

The main issue is the comma followed by the WHERE clause.

If the JOBDIVA_ID column is an attribute of the dbo.Repository table, then it looks like you are wanting an UPDATE command which would be:

```
UPDATE 
 dbo.Repository
SET
 STATE_CODE = 'SA',
 ZIPCODE = '560064'  
WHERE 
 JOBDIVA_ID = '23-00871';
```

If the JOBDIVA_ID was an attribute of a different table then you might be looking for:

```
insert into 
 dbo.Repository(STATE_CODE,ZIPCODE)  
SELECT
 STATE_CODE,ZIPCODE
FROM
 <other table>  
WHERE 
 JOBDIVA_ID = '23-00871';
```

Or maybe even (this makes no sense):

```
insert into 
 dbo.Repository(STATE_CODE,ZIPCODE)  
SELECT
 'SA' AS STATE_CODE,
 '560064' AS ZIPCODE
FROM
 <other table>  
WHERE 
 JOBDIVA_ID = '23-00871';
```

Answer (score -1):

In an insert statement you wouldn't have an existing row to do a where claues on.
You must use update statement depending on the data conditions